# Arduino SD count files and open last, How to?

Tags: sd-card, sd.h

I am trying to count files. I have one hidden file from Windows10 so i am doing "-1" but I want to open the last file and can't work out how, any help? Please, Thanks

```
#include <SD.h>
int entryCount = 0;
File root;
int total = 0;
int Lfile = 0;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  SD.begin(4);
  root = SD.open("/");
  printDirectory(root, 0);
  root.close();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print(total-1);
  Lfile = total-1;

  File dataFile = SD.open(Lfile);
  // if the file is available, write to it:
  if (dataFile) {
    while (dataFile.available()) {
      Serial.write(dataFile.read());
    }
    dataFile.close();
  }
  // if the file isn't open, pop up an error:
  else {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("error opening last file");
  }
}

void loop()
{
  // nothing happens after setup finishes.
}

void printDirectory(File dir, int numTabs)
{
  while (true)
  {
    File entry = dir.openNextFile();
    if (! entry)
    {
      if (numTabs == 0)
      return;
    }
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < numTabs; i++)
      Serial.print('\t');
    Serial.println(entry.name());
    total = entryCount;

    Serial.print(entryCount++);

    Serial.print('\t');

    entry.close();


  }
}
```

Comment: what does `last file` mean?

Comment: sd card have files log01.txt, log02.txt, etc. Last file is last file which was created

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [exist() method](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SDexists) found in the [SD.h library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SD) you already are including in your program.  Assuming you will create no more than 99 files and the last file created will have the highest 2 digit value as part of its name, test for the existence of the file log99.txt.  If not found, decrement the 2 digit number and test for the existence of file log98.txt.  Repeat this process until you find the newest file created.